# How to apply common css property for two seperate columns

Tags: css

I've two columns namely 'right_col' and 'left-col',both have different background colors.The problem is,left column will have dynamic data,So it is always changes and right column is static.Whenever left columns height increases its background is also applying to that extent height but right column have static data,I need to apply same height to right column,because left column is not constant,depending upon left column height,right column height also increase so,that its background will automatically apply upto that extent and seems to be fine.How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **display:table-cell** property for this. write like this:

```
.left,.right{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7nSqX/  .

It's work till IE8 & above.

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of different solutions for this, so i recommend reding [this great comparision of some techniques](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/) - choose the one that fits your needs best.

i'd choose the last one (*"Offset Columns and Containers"*) - the same approach that is explained in [this article on matthewjamestaylor.com](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks).

Comment: Ok,I'll refer that document,Thanks

Comment: first link is not working, can you please check it? and for he second one, one day i too found that link and tried myself. But i couldn't make it working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily with jquery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var left = $('#left_col'),
        right = $('#right_col'),
        left_height = left.css('height');
    right.css('height',left_height);
});
```